# ClassCast Exception at Runtime when I want to cast a Type into its Sub for cloning

Tags: java, exception, casting

IHello !

I want to clone an object "B" who has a supertype "A".
In the clone() method of "B", I call the super.clone() (method of "A"). This method returns a "A" type with the fields cloned and setted.

In the clone() method of "B", I get the "pre-construct" returned object from super.clone() and I want to continue to clone it. So I must cast it into a "B" type object.

No problem at compilation time but it crashes a ClassCastException at runtime.

Is it possible to turn an object into its subtype ?
Or must I clone all the fields (even the "A" class fields) in the "B" clone() method ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe a bit offtopic here, but i use BeanUtils.copyProperties() from apache commons assuming matching setters/getters are available. not sure how its implemented so it could have side-effects. im aware this doesnt answer the question but has helped me in the past when having similar issues

Answer (score 1):

Proper cloning requires the use of a virtual method, which is implemented in the lowest level that supports cloning, and--depending upon how cloning is implemented--is either overridden by every level beyond that which adds new fields that would require deep cloning, or is overridden by every derived class, period.

If all implementations of `clone` worked by calling `super.clone`, up to the point where the lowest-level class calls `object.clone`, then calling `clone` on a derived type which has been cast to the base type would yield an object of that derived type.  Unfortunately, the belief that `super.clone` is broken has resulted in many people using copy constructors instead of calling `super.clone`, thus creating an unfortunate self-fulfilling prophesy.

Given that unfortunate situation, the best one can do is probably to have each class whose parent exposes a `clone` method that might not chain to `object.clone`, expose a `protected` copy constructor which takes an instance of its type, chains to the parent class's copy constructor, copies any fields added by that derived type which are publicly exposed (or map to properties that are) or refer to immutable objects, and clones any fields of that derived type which are not publicly exposed and refer to mutable objects.  This approach will work, but it will be necessary for every class derived from a cloneable class to implement its own override of the virtual clone method, even if the only thing that method does is call the protected copy constructor of its own class.

If your parent class has a non-virtual cloning method which calls some kind of constructor without virtual dispatch, then it is not possible to properly implement any derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but I've found a solution :
I didn't know that in my clone() method of my super class, I had to get my object by calling super.clone() (native clone() from Object Class ?) and cast it into my type. ( I did explicit instanciation MySuperType t = new MySuperType() ).

Now, I get a MySuperType that I can downcasting in my sub class :
(MySubClass) sc = (MySubClass) super.clone();

Thank you, so I will write a post in my blog [www.patate-chaude.fr](http://www.patate-chaude.fr/) !